# TSS usage in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

While reading linux kernel code, I came across usage of `tss` (task state segment) inside `__switch_to` (arch/x86_64/kernel/process.c#L441).

Since linux handles saving/restoring process context via software, what is the need to maintain duplicate data? For e.g. stack pointer. Attaching a small snippet for reference

```
struct task_struct *__switch_to(struct task_struct *prev_p, struct task_struct *next_p)
{
    struct thread_struct *prev = &prev_p->thread,
                 *next = &next_p->thread;
    int cpu = smp_processor_id();  
    struct tss_struct *tss = &per_cpu(init_tss, cpu);

    unlazy_fpu(prev_p);

    /*
     * Reload esp0, LDT and the page table pointer:
     */
    tss->rsp0 = next->rsp0;
```

What is the need to copy `rsp0` from `next`(thread_struct) to `tss`(tss_struct). Why can't we use `next->rsp0` wherever `tss-rsp0` is used? Why is `tss_struct` still present in kernel?

I am a noob who has recently started to learn kernel insides.

Comment: What kernel are you looking at?  See https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.11.12/source/arch/x86/kernel/process_64.c#L266

Comment: My bad. I should have mentioned kernel version too. But in v4.11.12 (above linked) kernel too there is  `load_sp0(tss, next);` (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.11.12/source/arch/x86/kernel/process_64.c#L434) which eventually `tss->x86_tss.sp0 = thread->sp0;` (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.11.12/source/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h#L514). Why are we still maintaining `tss_struct` ?

Comment: Isn't that the per-cpu kernel stack?  It would be needed the next time the kernel is entered.

Comment: Hmmm. AFAIK there is nothing like "per-cpu stack" (only per process user stack and kernel stack). Anyway, after reading around I think I have got my mind around it.

Comment: How would two different cores run in kernel mode at the same time?  Of course each core has a kernel stack.

Comment: Are you suggesting there are three kinds of stacks : process stack in user space, process stack in kernel space, "cpu stack'? I think there are only two former kinds. In regards to your example, those cores would essentially be using kernel stacks of the processes that got interrupted. Wouldn't it?

Comment: I got this far in my understanding. Linux maintains per cpu TSS. Hence, when interrupt occurs, hardware uses TSS pointed to by `tr` register; specifically process kernel stack is restored into `esp` register with user kernel stack and user program `eip` pushed onto kernel stack. Hence, we need to setup `esp0` in per cpu `tss_struct` when context switching.

Comment: I was confused for a long time after reading that "Linux does not use hardware context switching". I came to understand that TSS and hardware context switching are independent entities. And linux (and hardware) utilise TSS for interrupts. What it actually means by hardware context switching is to update `tr` register with address to new TSS. Since linux keeps single TSS per cpu, it would not matter if underlying architecture performs hardware switching or not (since, there is practically no switching of `tr` registers as there is single TSS per cpu)

Comment: All that stuff with swapgs is complicated and I don't pretend to understand it all.  There are a lot of possible race conditions and security implications.